# C# Mock dependend validators with FluentValidator

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a validator like this:

```
RuleFor(a => a.Id)
    .IsRequired()
    .MustBeValidId()
    .MustExistInDatabase<Command, ChangeRequest>(context)
    .DependentRules(() =>
    {
         RuleFor(a => a.Description)
            .IsRequired()

         ...
    });
```

I want to test the `Description` property, which is evaluated only if the `Id` property is valid.

But for testing purposes, this wouldn't be necessary.

This test should pass:

```
GetValidator().ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(command => command.Description, "my description");
```

But it fails because the Id property fails to validate.

To test it, I would have to create an InMemory EFCore provider create the entity to check if it exists in database and then the `Description` validator would not fail.

Is there any way to mock the Id validator so I could easily test the dependant rules?

Answer (score 0):

The FV unit testing extensions end up running a validate under the covers.
Could you mock parts of the validator; probably! But I wouldn't do it in this case. The SUT should be the real deal and you should mock the dependencies (the db context).

I am assuming that the line `.MustExistInDatabase<Command, ChangeRequest>(context)` is the problem; what does that extension look like? It is possible to mock parts of a db context if you don't want to spin up/seed an in-memory db context.